My computer is lagging all of a sudden, task manager showed nothing
As the title mentioned, my computer just start lagging all of a sudden unknown reasons. I do not recognize any specific action that might cause the issue. I've experienced mostly input lags, obvious lags occur really often. Really don't know how to handle this kind of problem, reboot and the issue remains. Checked task manager and resource monitor nothing seems out of place (There are some hard error spikes in memory which have no idea what it means, but not quite as often as the lag anyway). Any possible solutions or suggestions for where to check will be appreciated. I'll try my best to provide any information if needed.
btw I have ubuntu 20.04 installed on D disk, but it never have caused  related problems despite being un&reinstalled several time. And I didn't un&reinstalled it for the past month too.
resource monitor (graph from top to bottom are CPU, Disk, Network, Memory)

device specifications

Device Name: LAPTOP-PHNQKA0S
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900H @ 2.50GHz 2.50 GHz
Installed Memory (RAM): 32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
Device ID: 2991DE01-54D3-4C02-A58D-161E402ABDEA
Product ID: 00325-82185-87765-AAOEM
System Type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based Processor
Pen and Touch: Pen support

Windows specifications

Version: Windows 10 Home
Version: 22H2
Installed on: ‎2021/‎8/‎24
Installed on: ‎2021/‎8/‎24
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0

SSD
PS C:\Users\brian2lee>  Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table -AutoSize

Number FriendlyName                    SerialNumber                             MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------                    ------------                             --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
1      NVMe CT1000P5SSD8               0000_0000_0000_0001_00A0_7521_2F9E_C1C7. SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 931.51 GB
0      NVMe SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00B00 0025_38B5_11B1_0FCF.                     SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 953.87 GB

Memtest86 test result


Use Task Manager and watch the processes when a lag spike happens. Also, test your hardware, specifically your memory and storage. There are plenty of good tools for doing that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@music2myear The lag happen really often, probably 1 to 2 lags in the time being of the resource manager graph. Task manager doen't show abnormal spikes in the mean while too.  I ran test using memtest86 after seeing ur comment, it passes and the result are showing above.

SSD or HDD? How old is the drive? [Edit] your question. Any additional screenshots should be in English

@Ramhound Updated ssd info, tried my best to provide info in English via translating or side notes since my system is in Chinese.

Lagspikes in Windows can have multiple origins.
The most obvious one is the CPU being busy all the time, but as obvious as this one is, it is also as obvious to see it happen in Task Manager, which you have ruled out.
The second option is memory. If something uses 100% memory, lag will also happen. This can also be easily spotted in Task Manager, so I'm gonna rule that one out too.
Corruption in memory can also be a reason, but you have ruled it out by running memtest. Bad settings in the BIOS can cause it too, but if that were the case, the system would always be laggy, not sometimes. We can rule that out too.
The harddisk can contian bad sectors which can also cause lag spikes, especially if there's a read/write at that specific sector. If this is the case, these will be logged in the EventLog. This should be investigated next.
The videocard can also cause lag, as in this case, it can't quickly update the screen, so it looks choppy. A problem with the videocard will almost always be a problem that keeps happening all the time, and not come and go, so we can rule this one out too.
A low battery in the mouse can also make the mouse cursor appear laggy. If this is the case, all the other programs run fine, and the problem is isolated to just the mouse.
When you connect to a different computer a slow internet connection can also cause lag. I just want to mention this, but its outside of the scope for this particular question.
Lastly, a process like a service can access memory, cpu and disk at the same time causing a combination of the above factors. A slowdown can be noticed but goes away quickly too because the service is done processing. This is usually something like indexing, a virus scan etc.
Services will be using the svhost.exe process, and the details tab of the task manager can view these.
A program like Process hacker (an advanced task manager) can see what service is related to which process which can help finding out what service is causing the lag.

The process hacker actually helped! Turns out asus's Armoury Crate is the problem, its private byte skyrocketed for unknown reason. Uninstalled it and the lag is significant reduced. Still don't understand why it seems normal in normal task manager. Really thanks for your help!

You're welcome. :) Glad I could help.
